# preg_match regex to split firstname, lastname

Tags: php, regex

I can't seem to figure this out... and I admit I'm not up to date with the new stuff. I was using `eregi_replace`, but switched it to `preg_replace` and added the delimiter. Now it is not working correctly.

I have fields that are in a form, that are sent to a form validator, and the error message lets the user know which fields are missing; i.e. "firstname, lastname, password, etc.". The error needs to show as "First Name or Last Name", basically adding a space and capitalizing the N in Name.

Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong?

This is what used to work:

```
$r .= ucwords(eregi_replace("_", " ", $c));
```

This is what I changed it to:

```
$r .= ucwords(preg_replace("/_/", " ", $c));
```

Now they just show as `Firstname`, `Lastname` but I would like them to show as `First Name`, `Last Name`.

Comment: You haven't shown any examples of your input data.  Please show some example inputs, and the actual outputs vs. the desired outputs.

Comment: `$c` is an array of what fields are missing, like `firstname`, `lastname`, if of course they are in fact missing (no input from user). Actual output vs. desired output is stated in the last sentence. I think I laid it out pretty clearly, or no?

Comment: No, it's not clear at all to me, anyway, in the absence of any example inputs.  Obviously the input string(s) must contain underscores.  I'm guessing the underscore is used as a delimiter and you want to replace them with spaces?

Comment: If we can't reproduce the issue we can't help. Post a reproducible example. https://eval.in/452198

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello it might be working like this:

```
<?php

$c = array('Firstname', 'Lastname', 'password');

foreach($c as $field_name)
{
    $r = ucwords(preg_replace("/name/i", " Name", $field_name));

    echo $r."<br>"; 
}
```

Comment: Yes, exactly. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your question and code didn't demonstrate what you were after.

```
$r .= ucwords(eregi_replace("_", " ", $c));
```

Never would have found `name`, that is looking for an underscore and replacing it with a space.

Which is why

```
preg_replace("/_/", " ", $c);
```

didn't work for you. That is a correct conversion but the regex is solving the wrong problem. Given the answer above another approach you could've, since a regex isn't needed, would be [str_ireplace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-ireplace.php).

```
$c = array('Firstname', 'Lastname', 'password');
foreach($c as $field_name) {
    $r = ucwords(str_ireplace("name", " Name", $field_name));
    echo $r."\n";
}
```

Demo: https://eval.in/452283

Comment: That's why it was confusing... because the code before, using `eregi_replace` worked. I didn't understand why. Either way, my desired outcome was laid out and explained. @Monomachus didn't have a problem figuring out what I meant, for which I am thankful.